# php secure comment logic?

Tags: php, database, logic

Ok, this might be obvious but its not clicking quite yet.  I am creating a forum/blog esque app.

I grab the posts from the database rather securely but commenting is beginning to be a little more difficult. (I could just be paranoid, right?).

How do I add a comment without exposing the id of the parent message? (like in a hidden form field or query string, or something).

I guess I am a bit paranoid that someone might go into the code with firebug or something and change the hidden form field value to something else before submitting. I guess I would have to make sure the user has permission to comment to that particular post/category?

Things to note :
The user is already logged in.
Its not a public post

Comment: "I guess I would have to make sure the user has permission to comment to that particular post/category?"  Yes.  Always check permissions after form submission.  In client-server applications, *never trust the client*

Comment: agree. you are not being paranoid, and you answered your own question.

Comment: Haha, you are probably right.  Just looking for the best ways to secure all types of database calls.  I have a good idea what I am going to do.  I will be back soon.  I appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you setup your database like so:

```
Comments
---------
id
encodedID
authorID
parentID
message
```

Then, for the form field have two hidden values, one will be the encodedID, and the second will be a hash that you make.  I would recommend the hash to be:

```
<?php

$hash = sha1(md5($encodedID . $userID . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "abc1234"));

?>
```

Then, when the user submits the form, validate that the hash is valid for the specific encodedID and user.  Here is a brief code write up:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //Get the variables and all and sanitize the input of 'message'
    if(sha1(md5($_POST['value1']. $userID . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "abc1234")) == $_POST['value2'])
    {
        //User is valid.
    }
    else
    {
        //Invalid user.
        //Document this.
    }
}

$value1 = $encodedID; //Grab this from your database
$value2 = sha1(md5($value1 . $userID . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "abc1234"));
?>

<form method="post" action="comment.php">
<input type="text" name="message" />
<input type="hidden" name="value1" value="<?php echo $value1; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="value2" value="<?php echo $value2; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" />
</form>
```

**Edit:** Just a small tip, but I would recommend that you change value1 and value2 to something abstract, don't call it encodedID or anything like that, just so that it confuses any users that will attempt to try and break it.

And yes md5 and sha1 are not completely secure, but for this case it will work since you want to be able to process the comments fast and efficiently.

Comment: Hashing the output of a hash function with a *smaller* output is a bad idea. You should simply re-hash the same data with a bit more entropy each time, or better yet, just hash it once.

Comment: I like this.  Going to try a couple things.

Comment: @Jeff Hubbard So something like:  sha1("abc1234567891011" . md5("smaller string")); is more secure?  It makes sense now that you mention it.

Comment: `sha1(md5())` smells like cargo cult programming.  You clearly don't trust either hash.  What makes you think that combining two hashes you don't trust will create a more trustworthy hash?

Comment: Regardless of arguments, this still gave me a good direction.  I think combining the current Date (day,hour,seconds,ms) in addition to something like the user ID would help create a good unique hash.

Comment: @Flipper There's no need to hash that static string constantly--calculate it once, and hardcode it. That's called a salt.

Answer (score 2):

That might be an overkill but if you really want to hide the post_id of the current message then you should consider using session. So instead of using something like this on your form:

```
<form action="/postcomment.php" method="post" >
   <input name="post_id" type="hidden" value="123" />
   <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</form>
```

Reduce it to something like this:

```
<?php $_SESSION['post_id'] = '123'; ?>

<form action="/postcomment.php" method="post" >
   <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</form>
```

Of course this is "yucky" coding but at least you get the idea.

Oh, don't forget to validate EVERYTHING on postcomment.php. Also escape ALL string input values and make sure all numeric inouts are numbers indeed (multiply them by one?).

[EDIT: Due to insistent public demand, may I, if you please, amend the aforementioned:]

Instead of:

```
<?php $_SESSION['post_id'] = '123'; ?>
```

Generate a form id:

```
<?php $_SESSION['form_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'].'_'.md5(time()); ?>
```

Then generate the unique post_id:

```
<?php $_SESSION[$_SESSION['form_id'].'_post_id'] = '123'; ?>
```

After submitting get the post_id:

```
<?php $post_id = $_SESSION[$_SESSION['form_id'].'_post_id']; ?>
```

Comment: What if the from is inline in the page and you open 5 posts in 5 tabs? The session will be overwrited with last one and if you comment on first, you will get the error. This however will work if the form is loaded in separate request and of course the user didn't go to another post and hit the comment reply there. So... this is not the right solution to go for forum/blog codding.

Comment: RRStoyanov is right.  This is only useful if the users will only be browsing each post one at a time.  I don't see sessions being able to work for this at all unless you keep a history of all of the posts looked at in the last 15 minutes, but still complicated and vulnerable.

Comment: As I've pointed out in advanced the code is in its simplest form in order to emphasize the general idea of using session instead of hidden fields ;)

Comment: I should of mentioned, there are multiple posts on one page, each with a comment section.  Moving in a good direction I think, though.

Comment: @Jhourlad Estrella But I am saying that sessions will not work at all for what he is trying to do unless you make some really weird abstract system which would still leave lots of holes.

Comment: @flipper: I agree form security is next to global warming. But we are already moving towards a greener world and the ozone layer is already closing up slowly. What I mean to say is form security is doable but we can't post all the codes here. I'm paid by the hour... :D

Comment: @Jourlad Estrella With your edit you would be storing so much more information than you really would have to.  Plus, what if the user keeps the window open for a while and the session expires?

Answer (score 0):

you could assign the form an "id" as a hidden field and create a database table to track form ids and their associated post ids, that way when the form gets submitted you could check the post id in the db without ever sending it to the client based on the form id that is returned with the post

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the wrong question here: instead of being concerned about the user getting some internal ID that means nothing outside your application, your primary concern *should* be about keeping them from doing anything unpleasant with it.

Imagine I just started sending POST requests to add a comment for every ID between 1 and 10,000. I'm sure to hit a real post sooner or later.

Rule #1 about writing secure web applications: **Don't trust the user.**

In other words, yes, you should check to make sure that they have permission to comment when you receive the results back from the from.